# Can the C++ module development of Twincat3 develop drivers

Tags: c++, module, twincat

Can the C++ module development of Twincat3 develop drivers . My driver matches my hardware, but it's not a product from Beckhoff . I want to develop the driver source code as a C++module to control my hardware .
Can it be achieved? What is the reason why it cannot be done?
I don't know how to match the entry function of the driver right now

Comment: I think everything can be done, question is more does it make sense. I never used the C++ module development of TwinCAT, but I did look into it. It looks way too complicated to achieve anything, hence why I never bothered with it. I would suggest you trying another approach. In case you want to do something, [here](https://hopperpop.github.io/posts/hello-world-in-twincat-c/) is a hello world example on how to get started.